# ContentResolver.insert() creates audio file of "audio/aac" mime type with .aac extension instead of .m4a

Tags: android, mediastore, android-contentresolver, android-audiorecord

The following codec creates audio file for AAC codec with .aac extension filename - `audio.aac` instead of `audio.m4a`:

```
val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
    put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_PENDING, 1)
    put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, "audio")
    put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000)
    put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE, "audio/aac")
    put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, "Music/My_App_Name")
}
val uri = contentResolver.insert(
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUri(volume),
    contentValues
)!!
```

Is there a way to create it with `.m4a` file extension filename without renaming the file later?

Comment: Put a display name with extension.

Comment: @blackapps I tried that but I get `audio.m4a.aac` file then :)

Comment: Then use the right type. Which ones did you try?

Comment: @blackapps I guess there is no right mime type to create it as `.m4a` file with `ContentResolver` and `MediaStore`.  AAC is codec but it also uses it as file extension.

Comment: Well did you try "audio/m4a"? Strange you are not reporting.

Comment: @blackapps yes, I tried - not supported exception

Comment: `"audio/*", "*/*"`.